# autoconf: Detect deprecated functions (in Glibc)

Tags: glibc, autoconf

Is there a way for Autotools to test a given function is deprecated in GNU libc?

I've been using AC_CHECK_FUNCS(readdir_r) to test whether a system has `readdir_r()` or not.  But now, since GNU Libc 2.24, `readdir_r()` is deprecated, I'd like to use `readdir()` on those system.

Does autoconf have a macro to test a give function is deprecated or not?  If not, what is the best way to handle this?

I know that newer GCC with `-Wdeprecated-declarations` prints a warning.  But what I'm looking for is to find deprecated function at configure time so that I can use the recommended function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily, because `AC_CHECK_FUNCS` checks whether the function is available at link time. What you could do would be to use `attribute.m4` (as shipped with, say, systemd), use `CC_CHECK_WERROR`, `CC_CHECK_FLAGS_APPEND` with `-Wdeprecated-declarations` and then use `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` to figure out whether the whole thing compiles.